# Why does two elif statments behave differently even though they are alike?

Tags: bash

For some reason this elif statement works

`elif [ $muteStat == 'no' ]; then`

while this

`elif [ $muteStat == 'no' ]; then`

returns this error

`./volumeControl.sh: line 34: [ no: command not found`

Why is this happening?

[image of the code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUza2.png)

Update: in the image the uncommented statement returns the error

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

#gets all connected sinks
sinks=$(pactl list short sinks | awk '{print $1}')


#mutes sink
mute() {
 pactl set-sink-mute $1 toggle
}

#adjusts volume of sink 
volume() {
 echo $1 $2
 pactl set-sink-volume $1 $2
}

#loops through all sinks and either mutes or adjusts the volume of them 
for sink in $sinks;
do
 if [[ $# = 1 ]]
 then
  volume $sink $1
 elif [[ $# = 0 ]]
 then
  mute $sink
 fi
done

#gets current volume 
currentVol=$(pactl list sinks | grep "Volume:" | awk '{print $5}' | head -n 1)
#checks if volume is muted, yes/no 
muteStat=$(pactl list sinks | grep -i mute | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}')

#sends different notification based on whether sound is muted 
if [ $muteStat == 'yes' ]; then
 notify-send -t 1200 "Sound is muted" "Volume is at $currentVol"
#elif [ $muteStat == 'no' ]; then
elif [ $muteStat == 'no' ]; then
 notify-send -t 1200 "Volume is at $currentVol"
fi
```

Comment: do you have a full example ?

Comment: Please provide more context. This means the surrounding code, if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $muteState has the value "no". Given the error message is complaining about the command "[ no" (all one word) is not found, it appears the whitespace after the bracket is not a simple space.

Look at the character codes of your script: `od -c script.sh` and look for "funny" characters. Actually, since it's only line 34, try `sed -n 34p script.sh | od -c`

---

Also, operands in the `[` command are subject to word splitting and filename generation, so variables should be quoted

```
if [ "$muteStat" = yes ] ...
    :
elif [ "$muteStat" = no ] ...
```

Also, the `==` operator is a bash extension to `[`, so if you're using bash, you might as well use `[[`

Also, numeric comparisons use different operators: `[[ $# -eq 1 ]]`

Comment: I'm curious as to which editor you are using to edit your scripts.

Comment: For now I'm using nano, recently started using linux. Thanks will look into it now!

Comment: Thanks, "302 240" appeared instead of a normal space, which looks to be a no-break space. No clue how that got there, again thanks for all help!